What are the weapons of Pradyumna and Kamadeva?
Does Pradyumna use the weapons of Kamadeva - bow and arrow I assume - since he is the espousal of Kamadeva? Maybe for that avatara,  Kamadeva becomes another, or is merged with another, or maybe kamadeva has many weapons, not just cute little bow and arrow.

Drawing his sharp-edged sword, he beheaded the asura.

